# User integer guessing game: How do I add another check to if loop

Tags: python

new to Python and Stack. As the title says I'm coding a guess number game. The instructions are as follows:

Write a program that prompts the user for an integer that the player (maybe the user, maybe someone else) will try to guess. If the player's guess is higher than the target integer, the program should display too high. If the user's guess is lower than the target integer, the program should display too low. The program should use a loop that repeats until the user correctly guesses the integer. Then the program should print how many guesses it took.

When you run your program it should match the following format:

```
Enter the integer for the player to guess.
-12
Enter your guess.
100
Too high - try again:
50
Too high - try again:
-2000
Too low - try again:
-12
You guessed it in 4 tries.
```

If the user guesses the integer in 1 try, then your program should print "You guessed it in 1 try."

My code:

```
print('Enter the integer for the  player to guess.')
secret_int = int(input())

guess_taken = int(0)

print('Enter your guess.')

while guess_taken < secret_int:
    guess = int(input())

    guess_taken = guess_taken + 1

    if guess < secret_int:
        print('Too low - try again:')

    if guess > secret_int:
        print('Too high - try again:')

    if guess == secret_int:
        print('You guesses it in', guess_taken, 'tries.')
        break
```

My code works fine but I can't seem to figure out how to add this provision "If the user guesses the integer in 1 try, then your program should print "You guessed it in 1 try." I've tried everything I can think of and nothings works, all out of ideas. Thank you and sorry for any formatting errors!

Comment: You print `You guesses it...` instead of `You guessed it...`, but you also need to conditionally print `try` when guessed in one else `tries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your final print line to this:

```
print('You guesses it in', guess_taken, ('tries.' if guess_taken > 1 else "try."))
```

Comment: Never would have thought of that, thank you! One quick question, why do we need to add another set parenthesis for the if statement?